# Changing a label's image on click

Tags: vb.net

Whilst trying to change a label's set image to a new image stored in resources it appears blank rather than showing the correct new image.

I've tried storing the images in resource and then call them on a button click in the form. This just changes the home1.png image to a blank image and doesn't show home2.png

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Resources As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager
        Label1.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("home1.png")
    End Sub
```

For ease of explanation i have two images

`home1.png`

`home2.png`

*home1.png* is the loading image when the app is loaded it's what will be displayed. When you click the button on the app *label1* image should change to use the *home2.png* file stored in resources. The code i have appears to show a blank image.

I have checked to make sure file names are correct and they are.

Comment: You tried without `.png`? `Label1.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("home2")`

Comment: Worked. I feel so stupid! Thank you.

Comment: Since you added the images to the project's resources, when you type `My.Resources.` in the code page, doesn't Intellisense show your named images in the resource file?